# Defining UIBarButtonItems in a closure of a property in the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to setup an array of UIBarButtonItems in property of the view controller through a closure.

So instead of doing this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let b1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "MoveUp", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b1Tapped(sender:)))
let b2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b2", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b2Tapped(sender:)))
let b3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b3", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b3Tapped(sender:)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [b3, b2, b1]
```

I did this:

```
lazy var bbItems: [UIBarButtonItem] = {
    let b1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "MoveUp", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b1Tapped(sender:)))
    let b2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b2", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b2Tapped(sender:)))
    let b3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b3", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(b3Tapped(sender:)))

    return  [b3, b2, b1]
}()
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = bbItems
```

I had to make it a lazy var for it to execute the functions connected to the buttons. When it was just a regular var it didn't execute it.

Is there any drawback in doing it like this. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can pass target to closure through parameters. i used Protocol to define a abstract type which have required functions for target.

it would be something like this in swift 4

```
// it should be @objc because selectors need functions that are visibile to Objective-C
@objc protocol NavigaitonBarConfigurable: class {
    func b1Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    func b2Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    func b3Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
}

/// create UIBarButtonItems
func createNavigationBarButtons(target: NavigaitonBarConfigurable) ->  [UIBarButtonItem] {
    let b1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "MoveUp",
                             style: .plain,
                             target: target,
                             action: #selector(NavigaitonBarConfigurable.b1Tapped(_:)))
    let b2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b2",
                             style: .plain,
                             target: target,
                             action: #selector(NavigaitonBarConfigurable.b2Tapped(_:)))
    let b3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "b3",
                             style: .plain,
                             target: target,
                             action: #selector(NavigaitonBarConfigurable.b3Tapped(_:)))
    return [b1, b2, b3]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // pass the function for creating buttons with target as self (self is NavigaitonBarConfigurable)
    lazy var bbItems: [UIBarButtonItem] = createNavigationBarButtons(target: self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(self.bbItems, animated: false)
    }
}

extension ViewController: NavigaitonBarConfigurable {
    func b1Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("b1")
    }

    func b2Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("b2")
    }

    func b3Tapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("b3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the target is going to be self  I am not sure what is being gained using your solution over just having it totally defined as a lazy var on the ViewController like I did it.

Comment: This is a general way to create a pattern in your application to avoid DRY. You can assign three buttons to every viewcontroller you want with 3 function which can be adopted differently by each controller. Also it separates your menubutton codes from rest of your codes. if you dont need to reuse the same code you can create and set your menu buttons in your viewcontroller. Also target can be anything other than self. You can assign any class as long as it adopts NavigationBarConfigurable.